# (MYSQL) Calculate average from a list of pupils who have some qualifications

Tags: php, mysql, sql, average

I would like to get the average of qualifications of each pupil.

For example, there are 30 pupils who have:

```
Pupil 1: Qualification 1: 5,6 Qualification 2: 3,2 Qualification 3: 9,1
Pupil 2: Qualification 1: 5,1 Qualification 2: 8,6 Qualification 3: 3,1
Pupil 3: Qualification 1: 1,9 Qualification 2: 7,2 Qualification 3: 5,1
Pupil 4: Qualification 1: 4,6 Qualification 2: 5,2 Qualification 3: 9,5
```

etc...

And i want to get:

[image]

I´ve tried with:

```
select distinct pupils.name, pupils.surname, qualifications.id_trimester, round(avg(qualifications.qualification),2), count(qualifications.qualification) from pupils, qualifications where pupils.level='1' and pupils.class='A'  and qualifications.id_trimester=1 and qualifications.type_qualification='class' group by pupils.surname.
```

But it shows the same average qualification and count for all the rows. It shows the average qualification of the first pupil repeated in all the rows...

The tables are:

```
pupils:

id_pupil
name
surname
email
user
pass
level
class

qualifications:

id_qualification
qualification
date
time
subject
id_pupil
id_user
id_trimester
type_qualification (misses, delayes or attitude)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify how the `qualifications` table should be joined to the `pupils` table.

```
select ... from pupils join qualifications using (id_pupil) where ...
```

Comment: This? select distinct pupils.name, pupils.surname, pupils.id_pupil,  round(avg(qualifications.qualification),2) from pupils join qualifications using pupils.id_pupil where pupils.level='1' and pupils.class='A' and qualifications.id_trimester=1 and qualifications.type_qualification='class'

Comment: That's because you ----ing changed my code... I wrote `using (id_pupil)` for a bloody reason!

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. However, it shows me only the two first pupils... 

select distinct pupils.name, pupils.surname, pupils.id_pupil, round(avg(qualifications.qualification),2) from pupils join qualifications using (id_pupil) where pupils.level='1' and pupils.class='A' and qualifications.id_trimester=1 and qualifications.type_qualification='class' group by pupils.id_pupil

Comment: Sorry, it was my problem with qualifications, your code works great, a lot of thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I see three problems.

- You should have `GROUP BY id_pupil` instead of just `surname`, in case two pupils have the same surname.
- You have not specified any join condition between the two tables.  This means that every pupil will get matched with every qualification - you really don't want that.
- You don't need `DISTINCT` - in fact, it's usually a bad idea to use `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` in the same SQL statement.